# Function transformation of exponentials

Tags: cv.complex-variables, special-functions, theta-functions

I came across the following function transformation:
$$
\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{(-j^2\cdot t)} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}} \cdot \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{(-\frac{\pi^2}{t}\cdot j^2)}
$$

where $ j \in \mathbb{Z}$ (i.e. integers).

Can anyone help me to understand why this relation is true? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the functional equation for the theta function. A nice proof (using Poisson summation) can be found [here.](http://math.mit.edu/~brubaker/Math784/thetafunctions.pdf)

Comment: This IS the Poisson summation:-)

Comment: Yes, of course.